# Программное создание таблицы в БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql

Где ошибка в формировании запроса?

```
string query = string.Format("if NOT EXISTS(SELECT name AS [table] FROM sys.tables    WHERE name='{0}')"+
                "CREATE TABLE '{1}' (PolzName nchar(8) not null, PolzPass nchar(8) not null,"+
                "PolzType nchar(13), PolzFirstName nchar(20), PolzLastName nchar(20))", tablname.ToString(), tablname.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE {1}
```

Одинарных кавычек не надо при создании таблицы.
И я бы еще проверил, что между закрывающей скобочкой в IF и CREATE TABLE есть пробел.

Comment: Спасибо, человече!